# git push heroku master: Cannot find file

Tags: reactjs, git, heroku

I am building a React application and loading images in the following manner:

The state of the app contains products like so

```
{
      title: "Sound",
      image: "microphone.jpg",
      subtitle: "This is a subtitle",
},
```

I use require to access the images, all the way from the root directory

```
let display = this.props.products[this.props.contentIdToDisplay];
<img src={require('/home/username/Documents/Coding/Heroku/crusade-1/src/assets/images/'+display.image)} className="product-image"/>
```

For some reason Heroku is unable to compile the build and spits out the following error message:

```
remote: Failed to compile.
remote: 
remote: ./src/components/Carousel.js
remote: Cannot find file '/home/username/Documents/Coding/Heroku/crusade-1/src/assets/images' in './src/components'.
```

The assets/images exists and contains all of the project's images and this code works fine in development. How can I get Heroku to recognise and compile the images?

Answer (score 0):

'/home/username/Documents/Coding/Heroku/crusade-1/src/assets/images/' is a reference to the filesystem on your personal computer.

Your need to reference the file relative to your project.

Say that you have a project like this

```
index.js
|_images // folder containing your images
|_react // folder containing your react components
```

Your img-tag could then look something like this

```
let display = this.props.products[this.props.contentIdToDisplay];
<img src={`/images/${display.image}`} className="product-image"/>
```